# Cmake target_include_directory not working

Tags: cmake

I'm currently learning Cmake, and I tried to make cmake linking my program

so,basically when I build cmake files this error appear: (https://i.stack.imgur.com/D0fZy.png)

and this is my cmake code:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.26.4)
project(TEST)

add_subdirectory(MathFunctions)

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} main.cpp)

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC MathFunctions)
target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC
                          ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include/Math
)
```

```
project(MathFunctions)
add_library(${PROJECT_NAME}  MathFunctions.cpp)
```

and here's my file structures:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/X5O44.png

I tried to do more research , but it's not going well.

Comment: Please refrain from using pictures for things that could be easily included as text in the question, such as error messages. Your file structure can be described in text as well like you can see for example in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54497465/should-i-use-only-add-executable-with-raw-cpp-files-or-make-a-library-via-add).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to ComicSansMS answer, you have yet another problem:

You are defining include directories for the wrong target, i.e., target `${PROJECT_NAME}` and the error is output during compiling of the `Mathfunctions` target.

your CMakeLists.txt should look like this:

root CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.26.4)
project(TEST)

add_subdirectory(MathFunctions)

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} main.cpp)

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC MathFunctions)
```

and the MathFunctions/CMakeLists.txt:

```
project(MathFunctions)
add_library(${PROJECT_NAME}  MathFunctions.cpp)
arget_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC
                          ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/include
)
```

Note the following:

- the `${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}` is used to reference the directory of the top level `CMakeLists.txt`
- since you are using the form `#include <Math/Mathfunctions.h`, the sub-directory `Math` is excluded from the include path
- include directory is added to `MathFunctions` target only and is inherited by all targets linking against it.

At the end, naming CMake projects test is considered bad practice, since it might interfere with test-related targets generated by the CMake.

Comment: YOO UR THE HERO, IT"S WORKIn

Answer (score 0):

Your path given to `target_include_directories` is incorrect.

The rules are as follows:

If in your `CMakeLists.txt` you have

```cmake
target_include_directories(my_app PUBLIC /a/b)
```

And in your C++ code you do

```cpp
#include <c/d.hpp>
```

This will correspond to the path `/a/b/c/d.hpp` on disk.

Your example fails because you list the `Math` subdirectory twice in the combined path.

See [this example on godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/b6dKssEdG) for a fully working, minimal example of this scenario.

Comment: this is true?
target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include)

it still throw an error
 fatal error: Math/MathFunction.h: No such file or directory
    1 | #include "Math/MathFunction.h"

Comment: @MinhTuệNguyễn Yes, that is how it works. See [this minimum example on godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/b6dKssEdG). You may have other errors in your project though that you did not include in the question which may cause it to fail. I'd suggest you start from the minimum working example and gradually add things back from your project until you find the place where it fails.

Comment: hey sir , here's my Mathfunction.cpp script
#include "Math/MathFunction.h"

int plus(int a,int b){
 return a+b;
}
and i use header to define function how to make cmake link my mathfunction.cpp
my file structure [here](https://i.imgur.com/GbNHCJ1.png)